# I have migrated to new gitlab instance but previuos runners need to re-register in new gitlab instance

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have installed new gitlab instance (self-managed version *ee-16.3.4*). I used to work with another installation which was connected to a *gitlab-runner* server (version 16.4). There were near 20 runners configured in gitlab-runner which I want to connect them to new instance. Due to some reasons, I could not backup/restore previuos gitlab instance to new one. Now, how can I use the same gitlab-runner server for new gitlab instance. is there any solution to re-register 20-runners in gitlab-runner server by renewing the registration tokens, or I have to register them in new instance one-by-one?
I read https://archives.docs.gitlab.com/15.11/runner/commands/#gitlab-runner-reset-token manual, but I didn't understand how `gitlab-runner reset-token` command would be useful. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You must register the runners again using `gitlab-runner register`. Each runner will need to request a new token using the registration token of the new instance.

Keep in mind, this will create a new section in your runner config.toml containing the new token. You will want to edit the configuration file to remove/replace the old registered configuration with the new one.